# What are the rules of substituting in a power series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I realize that to get the maclaurin of $e^{-2x^2}$ it is easiest to simply use the famous $e^x$ series and plug in $-2x^2$ for $x$ in all the terms.

What are the limits of this? For example, could I plug in $(x \pm A)$ where $A$ is a constant in a power series when I substitute? And I also saw that $|x\pm A|<1$ for it to work.

Are there any good tutorials on this? Thanks!

Comment: I guess this is one of those things that is easier to do than to explain. My advice: just do some exercise, and it will become natural to you.

Answer (score 1):

Let $g(x)$ be the function you want to substitute $x$ with in your power series $f(x)$.
In general, the image of $g$ (given a domain for $x$) must fall within the [interval of convergence](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/PowerSeries.aspx) of the power series. In other words, as long as you limit the domain of $g(x)$ in such a way that its image corresponds to a set of values of $x$ for which the power series $f(x)$ converges, the series $f(g(x))$ will converge over that domain.

As an example, $f(x) = \frac 1{1-x}$ has the Taylor/Maclaurin series $1 + x + x^2 ...$ (which is the geometric series). The interval of convergence is $(-1, 1)$, or as an inequality $|x| < 1$. Thus if you substitute $x+a$ into the series it would converge whenever $|x+a| < 1$ (as you noted).

Answer (score 0):

In practice, the substitution for a power series that converges in a neighbourhood of $0$ such as a Maclaaurin series, the substituted function must have limit $0$.